# How can I link to a specific comment on drupal.org?

Tags: community-official-site

I'm aware that you can use `[#1234]` syntax in posts on [drupal.org issue pages](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/drupal?categories=All).

However, is there any syntax to point to the specific comment, like: `[#1234:12]`?

I was using it before, but I forgot the syntax and I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: I usually mouse over the comment number, right click, and select copy link address.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> References to project issues in the form of `[#1234]` (or **`[#1234-2]` for comments**) turn into links automatically

That is from the very bottom of [compose tips](https://www.drupal.org/filter/tips).

So just replace the colon with a hyphen and your guess would have been perfect.